# Single thread blocks all other at WinSock recv()

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, sockets

I have a multi threaded program and every thread is something like:

```
thread() {
    connect();
     while(1) {
        recv();
        do_some_work();
    }
}
```

If you exchange *do_some_work()* with *sleep(5)* to simulate a load which blocks the thread and stops it from reaching it's recv() call all the other threads block at *recv()* for the amount of time that thread *sleep()*. There is data received I can see it with WireShark and those are video streams so they never stop sending.

I wonder why is that thread blocking all other threads when WinSock(2,2) is supposed to be multi-threaded ?

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR: It should not block the other threads.

UPDATE: Seem like the server is blocking all it's clients when a single  client doesn't read what is sent to it. I blame it on poor server design.

Comment: Windows has `Sleep`, not `sleep`. The point is - as other commenters have mentioned - the above code is not an SSCCE; your problem and the posted code seem to be orthogonal. I strongly encourage you to go and make a functional SSCCE as the chances are you'll discover the problem for yourself in the process and get an answer before anyone here can help you. If not, you have a functional example for the folks here to help with.

Comment: @kfsone I'll do that and I'm using mingw so I have sleep()

Comment: @kfsone Now it is SSCCE and in the output u can clearly see the 5 second gap created by the sleep in just one thread.

Comment: 'Thread-safe' has nothing to do with it. Do you mean 'multi-threaded'? And is your real problem that the real `do_work()` method has the same effect as the sleep? And if not, what is your real problem?

Comment: The real problem is that every reconnect make all the cameras stop for few seconds which is annoying and feels unprofessional to say the least :)
You can imagine a wall of 36 cams and all halt for 2-3 sec because of one reconnecting / connecting.

Comment: Every *reconnect.* So it has nothing to do with the read loop whatsoever, regardless of what's in it. You're wasting a lot of time here asking the wrong question.

Comment: Yes. If You for some reason manage to slow the reaching of _recv()_ in whichever thread ALL others block at _recv()_ and it's completely different sockets for every thread as you can see.

Comment: And I said reconnect because You happen to do some more complicated things when reconnecting. BUT every slowing down does the same thing. Regardless if its reconnect or say frame decode slowdown or sleep().

Comment: 'You happen to do some more complicated things when reconnecting' such as what? And why do you have to reconnect at all? What is causing that? And why are you ignoring the result of `recv()` in the handshake?

Comment: @EJP what does it matter ? It's ffmpeg stuff like allocating few contexts and things like that I cant touch there because its ffmpeg internal things . But that or even sleep does the same thing which is really wrong or bugged and the problem is winsock2. My question is if the Winsock2 blocking other threads expected behavior or not.

Comment: Winsock2 isn't blocking anything. Your code *appears* to be blocking Winsock2, which is a completely different proposition. NB Testing a `recv()` result for -1 only is not adequate. You have to store it into a variable, test it for -1, test it for zero, otherwise use it as the byte count received. It's difficult to believe this code works at all, as it can read too much data at any of the handshake receive points, and so get out of sync with the camera.

Comment: That code is not the real one that is used with the cams. Forget the other one. Focus on THIS. This current code BLOCKS on Winsock2 recv() which never receive anything UNTIL the sleep() in COMPLETELY different thread ends. like it or not. Go test it if u don't believe me. I cant Imagine You still can't understand that. I dont know how to explain it simpler. You see the code you see the output. There should NOT be 5 seconds gap. And you can see by yourself that NOTHING else is blocking it except sleep() in a DIFFERENT thread.

Comment: I agree. It blocks. The sleep blocks it. Winsock isn't blocking your sleep. Your sleep is blocking Winsock. Nobody can test this for you. We don't have your video server. It's no good ranting about it. Did you write the video server?

Comment: The sleep blocks ONE of the threads, BUT for some reason the other thread blocks too, how can you not understand that, it's so simple ? And it happens only with threads if I run 2 SEPARATE programs it doesn't happen. Sorry but I'm being frustrated how such a simple question has no answer.

Comment: I might have lied and the server may be the problem (it not written by me so its a black box). The "other program" is true when I use different video client and my program. But when I use 2 instances of my program it locks. Why that happens I'm not yet sure. Thanks for kicking my ass in the right direction. I though about it but I was sure it is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like the server is blocking all it's clients when a single client doesn't read what is sent to it. I can guess that it's a single thread that manages all connections and send() blocks because it doesn't use select() or something along those lines.